# Avoid application to be installed on tablet devices

Tags: android, tablet

I am working on an android application which supports android 2.1 and 2.2 version. And I do not want my app to get installed on any of the android tablet devices. Is there any way to achieve this in android like if we do any changes in manifest file of the app, something like that. Any help greatly appreciated... Or is there any way to prevent our app not to get listed in the market of tablet devices once we release the app. But It should be listed in the market of android mobile phones.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Depends on what kind of devices you really want to not support. What exactly is your criteria? A large screen? In that case, you could add</strike>

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="false" />
```

To your AndroidManifest.xml file. But really, it depends on what you're trying to block out here. There's a thin line between a tablet and a phone - they're running the same OS and have the same capabilities, down to the ability to make phone calls. Think about what feature exactly it is you want to use as a criteria, then find the proper value to use in the manifest file.

This whole answer is nonsense, I'm just keeping it here for Dianne's comment since that's the only voice of reason here. Bottom line - A tablet is a normal Android device, it'll run the same software.

Comment: Hello EboMike. Thanks for the reply.I need my app to support in 854 resolutions (eg, Droid) and not on samsung galaxy tab. Is it possible to make the app not to get listed in the android market of tablet devices.

Comment: Your AndroidManifest.xml file contains criteria that tell the market what your app supports. minSdkVersion=8 for example will hide the app on the Market for anybody who doesn't have Froyo or better. The line I sent in my reply will hide the app for anybody with a large screen.

Comment: We have droid devices in froyo too. So I want to make the app supporting in all android 2.1 and 2.2 mobiles but not on tabs. The above case wil not work in mobiles too ??

Comment: largeScreens="false" will hide the app in the Market on devices with large screens. Please read my answer.

Comment: I have read the answer. But mobiles like droid will come under large screens only. So if we give largeScreens="false" in manifest, then it will not work in droid too. But I want my app to work in droid also.

Comment: (1) Coding to a specific screen resolution like 854 is guaranteed to cause you trouble; (2) Droid is not a large screen, it is normal as per http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range; that said, (3) android:largeScreens="false" does *not* mean your app will be filtered, it means it doesn't understand large screens so on a large screen device it will be run in compatibility mode.  There is no way to filter out large screens because, by definition, if an app will work on a smaller screen it can work on a large screen through the compatibility mode.